# Meaning of square brackets in a Preview search

Tags: pdf, preview

I recently needed to search for a string enclosed in square brackets in a PDF document. So I typed `[concept]` into the search field (including the square brackets).

The result surprised me, as I got a list of pages containing the word `concept` with all letters contained in that word highlighted in yellow.

I haven't been able to find any documentation of this "feature" - or any other special syntax in the search field.

What is the straight explanation for this behaviour, if any?

Comment: It might be a bug that has been solved in the meantime, but I can't reproduce it (macOS 10.12.6).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the search is actually a Regular Expression search, and by enclosing your search term in brackets, instead of searching for the word 'concept' you were searching for the presence of the letters 'c', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'p' and 't'.

Comment: I had that thought, too, but it seems to me that it only applies to pages that contain the string "concept" - otherwise it should select all pages, as they all contain at least one occurrence of the characters in the bracket.

Comment: You are right, I did a test and it's a very odd result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the open bracket `[` is the problem so if you search for `concept]` then you'll at least get items that end in that sequence.

Comment: The question seems to be asking what the OP did, not what he's trying to do.

Comment: But it *does* provide some kind of workaround, which could be useful to future readers.